# Using jQuery plugins in greasemonkey (i.e. tipsy)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, greasemonkey

I'm trying (and for the most part succeeding) to use the tipsy jQuery plugin in my greasemonkey script. I am using the @require meta tag to import the jquery and tipsy js, and it works, but with a couple caveats which I'm trying to overcome.

Accessing elements as a pure jQuery object fails, so I'm relegated to using DOM functions to get my elements:

```
//this fails
$('#login').find('a:first').tipsy(); 

//while this succeeds
$(document.getElementById('login').getElementsByTagName('a')[0]).tipsy();
```

Anyone know why? Need more info? TIA!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's because inside Greasemonkey, jQuery has a different default context than the document. Try this:

```
$("#login", document).find('a:first').tipsy();
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, given the way that [jQuery context selectors work](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1), would it be faster to use `$(document).find('#login a:first').tipsy();`?

Comment: Given the amount of objects that i'm selecting (barely a handful), performance was not even discernible between the two methods, but it's worth checking on in a benchmark situation.